# The mail server logs will indicate time out when some customer sent the email to us

Tags: email, email-server

We are using the Icewarp mail server with version: 11.1.2
Recently the mail server will indicate time out in the logs when some customers sent the email to us.

It is the same even thought I added the customer email server IP to the trust IP list.

Refer to below one example extracted from logs( below I use mycompany.com representing my company domain & customer.com representing customer domain)

```
xx.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:33:04 Connected, local IP=192.168.1.4:25
xx.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:33:04 >>> 220 mycompany.com ESMTP IceWarp 11.1.0.1 x64; Mon, 19 Jan 2015 09:33:04 +0800
xx.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:33:04 <<< EHLO customer.com
xx.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:33:04 >>> 250-xxx.com Hello customer.com [x.x.x.x], pleased to meet you.
xx.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:33:04 <<< MAIL FROM:<Aifi@customer.com> SIZE=12894
xx.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:33:04 >>> 250 2.1.0 <Aifi@customer.com>... Sender ok
xx.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:33:04 <<< RCPT TO:<chlo@mycompany.com> ORCPT=rfc822;chlo@mycompany.com
xx.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:33:04 >>> 250 2.1.5 <chlo@mycompany.com>... Recipient ok
xx.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:33:04 <<< DATA
x.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:33:04 >>> 354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself
xx.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:38:04 <<< 0 bytes (overall data transfer speed=0 B/s)
xx.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:38:04 *** <Aifi@customer.com> <chlo@mycompany.com> 1 0 00:00:00 TIMEOUT 201501190933048591
xx.xx.xx.xx [0F9C] 09:38:04 Disconnected
```

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem lies in your costumer.

Your server expect that the client (costumer) will sent email content after `354 Enter mail, end with "." on a line by itself`. Unfortunately the client doesn't send any data after 5 minutes (09:33:04 -- 09:38:04) thus exceeding timeout from the server. Because server doesn't want to spend their resources on silent (and misbehaving) client, your server disconnect the connection.

Resourse: [RFC5321](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5321.txt)

Comment: In the begin, i also thought the issue is related to customer.
But there are about more than 10 customers facing the same issue.Any advise.

Comment: Yes, your server was act according to standard. **Without details about how the costumer behave**, then we have no more data to troubleshooting it. Check if the costumer apps was really sending data, check also maybe some firewall drop the packet.

Comment: Hi, all the related customer is coming from the same ISP.
So we reported this issue to my ISP and it is solved.
Thanks.